# Creating a suggested order variable in R

Tags: r

I have a brief question that probably has a simple solution, but frankly am just not sure how to go about this.

Let's say I have a quantity called available quantity. When this quantity goes below 0, I need to purchase more of an item. I have to buy said item in multiples of another quantity, let's call it reorder quantity.
I want to find the multiple of the reorder quantity that will make the quantity available > 0, and store that number in variable called suggested order.

Here's a brief example.

```
available_qty = -5000
reorder_qty = 1200
```

In this case the multiple would be 5, and the value that I would like to store in the suggested order variable would be 6000. How would I go about calculating this in R?

Comment: The multiple would be `ceiling(-available_qty / reorder_qty)` and the suggested order would be `reorder_qty * ceiling(-available_qty / reorder_qty)`

Comment: Thank you! That works great. I was going to use the %/% operator and store that value and add 1 to it but this is much simpler. Thanks! @AllanCameron